# Checking if key exists in Presto value map

Tags: presto, trino

I am new to Presto, and can't quite figure out how to check if a key is present in a map. When I run a `SELECT` query, this error message is returned:

`Key not present in map: element`

```
SELECT value_map['element'] FROM
mytable
WHERE name = 'foobar'
```

Adding `AND contains(value_map, 'element')` does not work

The data type is a string array

```
SELECT typeof('value_map') FROM mytable
```

returns `varchar(9)`

How would I only select records where 'element' is present in the `value_map`?

Comment: If the column type is a `varchar`, then it’s a string, not a map. Can you show some example values for the column?

Comment: There is a typographical error -- `SELECT typeof(value_map)` would show the type of the `value_map`. `SELECT typeof('value_map')` shows the type of the `'value_map'` string literal.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can lookup a value in a `map` if the key is present with [`element_at`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#element_at), like this:

```
SELECT element_at(value_map, 'element')
FROM ...
WHERE element_at(value_map, 'element') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

`element_at` is ambiguous in that case -- it'll return NULL when either there's no such key or the key does exist and has NULL associated with it. A guaranteed approach is `contains(map_keys(my_map), 'mykey')`, which admittedly should be a bit slower than the original variant.